# Bootstrap 3 Modal shown as full white screen

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a nav menu which opens different remote pages on modal. It was working without a problem but I guess, recently, I changed something on the page without noticing and now all I can see is a full page white screen whichever link I click on the nav menu.

I checked if I load the jquery script before the bootstrap.
I checked on different browsers (chrome, ie, android) and it is still the same.

Here is the page where I get the problem:
http://tvyerine.com

Try to click nav links on the upper menu.

What am I missing here?

[image]

Comment: It seems your modals are just empty...

Comment: What do you mean by saying empty? They all have href attributes to a remote page?

Comment: Yes, and that is exactly why it is not working.

Comment: I couldn't get what you trying to say. It was working a few hours ago without a hitch via that href attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the problem. The reason of the problem is not about the usage of href attribute for remote modals or using PHP pages instead of HTML.

Believe it or not the problem caused of the analytics script I use on the remote pages.

I do not know which part of the below code could cause this problem but when I remove it, everything is back to normal. BTW; Google Analytics works without a problem.

```
<!-- Start of StatCounter Code for Default Guide -->
<script type="text/javascript">
var sc_project=XXXXXXX; 
var sc_invisible=1; 
var sc_security="8c366369"; 
var scJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ?
"https://secure." : "http://www.");
document.write("<sc"+"ript type='text/javascript' src='" +
scJsHost+
"statcounter.com/counter/counter.js'></"+"script>");
</script>
<!-- End of StatCounter Code for Default Guide -->
```

Comment: awesome, I was under the impression that modals href don't play well with PHP pages. Still, you might want to reconsider if you will be updating to bootstrap 4.